# nonlinear programming with inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am confused about a nonlinear programming constrained to the region

$$X = \{(x1,x2) \in\mathbb{R}^2: (x1^2/a^2)+(x2^2/b^2)<=1\}$$

Can anyone show the steps of solving such a problem (for some arbitrary objective function)? 
Is there any special property of this constraint?

Comment: It's an inside of ellipse.

Comment: yes, it is. Does this mean I have a convex constrain? what can I do with a convex constrain?

Comment: Yes it's convex, of course.

Comment: Yes. How do I approach this problem then? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: For arbitrary objective function, it is arbitrarily hard. For a linear objective it is trivial as you can solve the problem analytically. Hence, more information required to answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your feasible set is convex. Whether this helps you will depend on your objective function (and in particular, on whether the objective is *also* convex.)

Because your constraint is so simple, one general approach is to try both cases where the constraint is active or inactive:

1. Ignore the constraint and solve the unconstrained optimization problem (this may or may not be challenging in and of itself, depending on how nasty the objective function is.) For each solution, check if it lies inside the ellipse.
2. Maximize(/minimize) the objective function on the boundary of the feasible region, which in this case has the easy parameterization $x1 = a\cos\theta, x2 = b\sin \theta.$ For each solution, check that the gradient of the objective function at the solution points out of(/into) the ellipse.

Comment: Thank you very much. I read some other questions, and people try to find derivative of Lagrangian of object function, then set partial derivatives to zero. Should I do the same? By the way, I am thinking of really simple object functions like x+y or something like this

Comment: @Mengge Yes, you can convert the constrained optimization problem into an unconstrained problem by adding a Lagrange multiplier. However think about what the method of Lagrange multipliers is doing: it's encoding the geometric fact that the solution (1) either lies inside of the feasible set ($\lambda=0$) or (2) lies on the boundary of the feasible set, with the gradient of the objective parallel to the gradient of the constraint ($\lambda>0$.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the interior of the ellipse and it's convex of course.

Comment: Yes. But I am doing optimization problem with this constrain. I didnt give the exact object function. It could be any simple example object function you want